# Fixing Vertices in Layout (KKLayout) JUNG/JUNG2

Tags: layout, jung, jung2

I am new here.. MY Question : 
 i have used KKLayout for visualization a graph. The Graph is created in while-Loop (after each iteraion) after a new Calculation and every time the vertices is placed on random Locations/Postions. I want to fix them, so that they placed on same Position after each Loop-Iteration. How can i fix them ???? thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the force-directed layouts start with their vertices in random positions; this is why you're seeing this behavior.

There are a couple of different approaches that you can take to resolving this issue.

(1) Use the `Layout.setInitializer()` method to specify a consistent starting position for each vertex.  This will ensure that `KKLayout` always does the same thing.

(2) If there is a specific layout result (set of positions) that you like, you can use `StaticLayout` initialized with those positions.  `PersistentLayoutImpl` can be useful for serializing/restoring those positions if desired.

Comment: thank u so much 4 replying.. 
Actually i am using first Time JUNG2-Library in Java.. Can u give me one Example : How i can use Layout.setInitializier() and maybe staticLayout..
I want only : After each Claculation the Vertices's Postion staying same, so that man can concentrate on Calculation and not first on their Position and then their Calculation. 
Again Bundle of thanks..

Comment: There's at least one sample in the JUNG distribution that uses StaticLayout; I suggest you take a look at those.

Comment: Can i fix the Location of Vertices, which is generated after first Iteration through KKlayout??

Comment: You can at any time iterate over the positions stored in the `KKLayout` instance.  `KKLayout` is an `IterativeLayout`, so each time `step()` is called the positions will advance.  (step() is usually called automatically, but you can manage this manually if you like.)  You can also create a StaticLayout based on a KKLayout instance; again, I recommend looking at the samples for example code.

Comment: thanx... i cannot call the Example Code :(:( .. i dont know, why :(.. i ll try it again .. thanks again ..

Comment: Code : 

Layout<String, Edge> layout = new KKLayout(g);        
JFrame frame = new JFrame(" shortest Path");
layout.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));

In each Iteration : creation a new "layout'' with random Coordinates from Nodes after new Calculation.
What i want : I want to fix the Coordinates from Nodes after first Creation of Layout, so that the fixed oordinates will be taken over from new "layout" in new Iteration.